# MySQL query WHERE length is longer than 1

Tags: mysql

I want to only show results where the length of a BLOB is greater then 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE OCTET_LENGTH(blob_field) > 1
```

Comment: It might be important to note [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58234) on slow `OCTET_LENGTH()` performance when checking BLOBs. It may have already been fixed (though it was shown as still being Open), and it may only apply to the InnoDB engine.

Comment: mmm that did not work when I run it in PHP, but when I run it in MYSQL it works